# How can i convert my python dictionary to below format

Tags: python

my dictionary:

```
[
  {
    "male_Unmarried": 792,
    "male_Husband": 13192,
    "male_own_child": 2823,
    "male_not_in_family": 4430,
    "male_wife": 2,
  }
]
```

expecting:

```
    [
      {
        "label": "male_Unmarried",
        "value": 792
      },
      {
        "label": "male_Husband",
        "value": 13192
      },
      {
        "label": "male_own_child",
        "value": 2823
      },
      {
        "label": "male_not_in_family",
        "value": 4430
      },
      {
        "label": "male_wife",
        "value": 2
      }
    ]
```

how can i convert first dictionay like second one.

I want for each dictionay of first one 
the key will be label and value will be value of first dictonary.

Please have a look

Comment: Do you actually want to JSON-ize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list-comprehension:

```
lst = [
  {
    "male_Unmarried": 792,
    "male_Husband": 13192,
    "male_own_child": 2823,
    "male_not_in_family": 4430,
    "male_wife": 2,
  }
]

print([{'label': k, 'value': v} for k, v in lst[0].items()])

# [{'label': 'male_Unmarried', 'value': 792}, 
#  {'label': 'male_Husband', 'value': 13192}, 
#  {'label': 'male_own_child', 'value': 2823}, 
#  {'label': 'male_not_in_family', 'value': 4430}, 
#  {'label': 'male_wife', 'value': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=[ {"male_Unmarried": 792,"male_Husband": 13192,"male_own_child": 2823,
"male_not_in_family": 4430,"male_wife": 2,} ]
lst_new = [{"label":i,"value":a[0][i]} for i in lst[0]]
lst_new     
[{'label': 'male_Unmarried', 'value': 792},
 {'label': 'male_wife', 'value': 2},
 {'label': 'male_own_child', 'value': 2823},
 {'label': 'male_not_in_family', 'value': 4430},
 {'label': 'male_Husband', 'value': 13192}]
```